# How to configure 1440x900 on two monitors in mirror displays?

Tags: intel-graphics, resolution, hdmi

complex issue. i bought my Mom a new desktop pc, with specs listed below (using HardInfo 0.5.1):

- Processor     : 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3450 CPU @ 3.10GHz
- Memory        : 3943MB (1228MB used)
- Operating System      : Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
  -Resolution     : 1024x768 pixels
  -OpenGL Renderer        : Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Desktop
- X11 Vendor        : The X.Org Foundation
- Genius Multimedia Keyboard
- ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse
- Venus USB2.0 Camera

Two screens are connected - a 19" monitor through DVI, and a 26" HDTV through HDMI.

[image: Displays Menu with TV]

Ubuntu Displays shows that I can mirror displays with 1024x768 & 1440x900.

[image: low res]
[image: high res]

Obviously I wanted the latter. Yet it doesn't work. 1024x768 does work, with no issues at all, but when i try to set the 1440x900 - the screens flicker, it take quite a while - and eventually doesn't work, as you can see here:

[image: error 1]
[image: error 2]

no only that - i must restart the computer since it becomes super slow, until i get a kernel panic. I sent the computer to the lab, and they claimed everything is ok with the hardware. They installed Windows 7 and showed me everything is fine, as seen here:

[image: Windows 7 Display Menu]

Comment: That graphic card is the only one you have? Don't you have another like Nvidia or ATI?

Comment: What's the point? Installing proprietary drivers that are even worse?

Comment: Yes - only an Intel card. No Nvidia on the board at all

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and I still can not solve it, or can find anything helpful on how to fix. While reading online about it, I discovered that this is a bug. The problem arises when you try to do a multi-monitor setup with one monitor in a DVI port, and another in a HDMI. My suggestion is, do you have a VGA or DVI port on the HDTV. You could connect your HDTV with a VGA or DVI(DVI if you have two ports for it on your graphics card). This might work.

Also, does this graphics card have a Nvidia Chip on it. If so, you might have The `Nvida X Server Settings` application on your computer. From there, you can enable Xinerama and also Twinview. There might even be an option there to mirror.

I would give this issue some time, because eventually, it will be fixed, or a solution will be found.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks. The PC is with an Intel card, and connecting the HDTV through DVI is a mess - since it's quite far away (i bought an expensively long HDMI capable to connect the two together..)

Comment: Bug #1039925 reported. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1039925

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot check but for XFCE and LXDE I use next script:

```
     #/bin/bash
     xrandr   --newmode   "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083          1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
     xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "1920x1080_60.00"
     xrandr --output  HDMI1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
     xrandr --auto --output HDMI1 --left-of VGA1
```

Via xrandr you can find your monitors and resolutions mode and configure Display positions.